# Find Participants with Completed Goals based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

A tibble: 1,540 x 3

| ID | Date | Form.Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | Complete |
| 2 | 2021-01-06 | Complete |
| 2 | 2021-02-10 | Complete |
| 3 | 2021-01-22 | NA |
| 3 | 2021-02-01 | Complete |
| 3 | 2021-02-23 | Incomplete |
| 3 | 2021-03-23 | Partial |
| 3 | 2021-04-13 | Partial |
| 3 | 2021-05-05 | Incomplete |
| 4 | 2021-01-15 | NA |

... with 1,530 more rows

I need to report which IDs achieve the following conditions (Form.Goal: 1= achieved, 0=not achieved):

> "At least 1 complete form OR 2 partial forms every month for 4 consecutive months"

I am having a difficult time trying to map this out. Here is what I have so far but keep coming up short:

```
df2<- df %>%
  drop_na(Date) %>%
  filter(Form.Status == "Complete" | Form.Status == "Partial") %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(n() >= 4) %>%
  mutate(consec = if_else(
    (Date - lag(Date) >= 30) & (Date - lag(Date) <= 31), 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(Form.Goal= if_else(sum(consec, na.rm = T) >= 4, 1, 0))
```

Obviously the above doesn't even begin to address partial form completions or mixed completion types per ID (for instance, Complete, Partial, Partial, Complete, Complete). I have seen different solutions to find consecutive dates with lubridate here, but I can't make it work with the above conditions.

The final dataframe would need to look something like this:

| ID | Form.Goal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 |

Thank you for any help with this!

Comment: How do you define "every month for 4 consecutive months"? Would March 31 + April 1 count as two consecutive months?

Comment: Why are 1 and 3 not meeting goal when they have a Complete?